# How should I make a poll for my website?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to make a poll for my website.The poll I want should look like the poll on http://www.premierleague.com/en-gb.html.I am not sure if I should use PHP,Javascript or etc to make a poll.Can anyone help me in this? Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to create a form and receive the data on the server side using PHP. Then you're going to put that information into a database.

I hope I do not come across as too mean but, the decision on which language to use is pretty simple when compared to actually coding it. I'm betting you are not entirely experienced with web-based programming languages. I would strongly suggest you look for some pre-made scripts in the interim:

Here is a simple tutorial on creating polls: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/creating-a-web-poll-with-php--net-14257

If you are OK with the idea of using a CMS, Here is a WordPress Plugin that should do the trick: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/creating-a-web-poll-with-php--net-14257

Otherwise, it's important to understand the flow of data:

1. Display the poll to the end user (use HTML forms and CSS to style)
2. Client submits data (either built in submit functionality or Ajax)
3. Server Receives data and stores it into database (php)
4. Page is re-loaded and results are displayed (read with php, then displayed using html/css)

In other words, you are going to use many of the available languages and tools to create a polling script.

Start with a pre-built one and look up other resources to learn to make/customize your own.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to save poll values, than PHP/MySql + JS for live effects, animations + CSS for styling.

1. Create database tables.
2. Create HTML form.
3. Style form to fit your needs (maybe jQuery UI).
4. Use Ajax to submit form.
5. Use PHP to gather information form user, validate it and save to database.
6. Reload user poll view to see changes.
7. Sell this masterpiece to Google/MS/Apple (or any other company).
8. Take big cup of hot chocolate.
9. Rule rest of the world.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use **PHP** or **any server side scripting** for validating, storing, processing poll, and use **HTML/CSS/JS** for client side, this is the main whole web page. You should also have **DBMS** (Database Management System) like mySQL, msSQL, etc., for storing poll answers.